# Convert dataframe column from Object to numeric

Tags: pandas

Hello I have a conversion question.   I'm using some code to conditionally add a value to a new column in my dataframe (df).  the new column ('new_col') is created in type object.  How do I convert 'new_col' in dataframe to float for aggregation in code to follow. I'm new to python, tried several function and methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
conds = [(df['sc1']=='UP_MJB'),(df['sc1']=='UP_MSCI')]
actions = [df['st1'],df['st2']]

df['new_col'] = np.select(conds,actions,default=df['sc1'])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Doesn't `df['new_col'].astype(int)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried astype(float), got value Error.  Talked to teammate, tried df.to_numeric(np.select(conds,actions,default=df['sc1'])).  That worked.